# DHTMLX Scheduler tooltip

Tags: tooltip, dhtmlx-scheduler

I'm showing the DHTMLX scheduler in a wizard and the tooltip is displaying behind the wizard.
How can i show it in the foreground?
Thanks.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptsve.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is the problem with css [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) property, Please change the z-index to a higher value.

```
.dhtmlXTooltip{
  z-index: 100;
}
```